# How to check if character exists in DataFrame cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After creating the three-rows DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['1-2', '3-4', '5-6']})
```

I check if there is any cell equal to '3-4':

```
df['a']=='3-4'
```

[image]

Since `df['a']=='3-4'` command results to `pandas.core.series.Series` object I can use it to create a "filtered" version of the original DataFrame like so:

```
filtered = df[ df['a']=='3-4' ]
```

[image]

In Python I can check for the occurrence of the string character in another string using:

```
string_value = '3-4'
print('-' in string_value)
```

What would be a way to accomplish the same while working with DataFrames?

So, I could create the filtered version of the original DataFrame by
checking if '-' character in every row's cell, like:

```
filtered = df['-' in df['a']]
```

But this syntax above is invalid and throws `KeyError: False` error message.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `str` and `contains`:

```
In [5]: df['a'].str.contains('-')
Out[5]: 
0    True
1    True
2    True
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it using query:

```
In [4]: df.query('a.str.contains("1")')
Out[4]: 
     a
0  1-2

In [5]: df.query('a.str.contains("-")')
Out[5]: 
     a
0  1-2
1  3-4
2  5-6
```