# How to Check and Filter out Row in Dataframe if "." exists in df Cell

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to reference this SF answer: [How to check if character exists in DataFrame cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39299703/how-to-check-if-character-exists-in-dataframe-cell)

It gave a seemingly good solution but it doesn't appear to work for a period character "." Which of course is the character I'm trying to filter out on.

```
df_intials = df['Name'].str.contains('.')
```

Is there something specific about filterting through a dataframe that every value in the column has a "."?

When I convert to a list, and write a simple function to append strings with the character "." to it works correctly.

Comment: Try `df_intials = df['Name'].str.contains('\.')` or `df_intials = df['Name'].str.contains('.', regex=False)`

Comment: Yep that did it. Want to submit that as the correct answer? I'll mark it as such.

Comment: Default is regex=True and "." in regex means any character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.Series.str.contains` uses regex expressions as default, so you can either use the escape character backslack or parameter `regex=False`:

Try

```
df_intials = df['Name'].str.contains('\.')
```

or

```
df_intials = df['Name'].str.contains('.', regex=False)
```